# Webstorm stops process when Break on Exception is enabled

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I have recently upgraded the node version of my project from 0.12.X to 4.2.4
Now whenever I run the project with debug and have "Break on Exception" (the lightning symbol) turned on. The application simply exits with the message:

`Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)`

No other error is reported anywhere.
The problem doesn't happen if I run without debugger or if I turn "Break on Exception" off.

I tried various options withing the "Break on Exception" configuration but nothing helped.

Any idea what may be causing it?

Webstorm 11.0.3

Node.js 4.2.4

EDIT: I am getting the following error in the log

`2016-01-07 11:30:40,786 [ 104966]  ERROR - ins.io.ChannelExceptionHandler - Expected a string but was NULL at line 1 column 314 
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expected a string but was NULL at line 1 column 314
    at org.jetbrains.io.JsonReaderEx.a(JsonReaderEx.java:1479)
    at org.jetbrains.io.JsonReaderEx.nextString(JsonReaderEx.java:826)
    at org.jetbrains.io.JsonReaderEx.nextString(JsonReaderEx.java:778)
    at org.jetbrains.v8.protocol.V8ProtocolReaderImpl$Mb.<init>(V8ProtocolReaderImpl.kt:501)
    at org.jetbrains.v8.protocol.V8ProtocolReaderImpl$M1.<init>(V8ProtocolReaderImpl.kt:146)
    at org.jetbrains.v8.protocol.V8ProtocolReaderImpl.readBreakEvent(V8ProtocolReaderImpl.kt:17)
    at org.jetbrains.v8.BreakEventHandlerKt.processBreak(BreakEventHandler.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.v8.EventMap.handleResponseWithHandler(EventMap.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.v8.V8CommandProcessor.acceptNonSequence(V8CommandProcessor.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.v8.V8CommandProcessor.acceptNonSequence(V8CommandProcessor.kt:14)
    at org.jetbrains.rpc.MessageManager.processIncoming(MessageManager.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.v8.V8CommandProcessor.processIncomingJson(V8CommandProcessor.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.v8.StandaloneV8Vm$2.consume(StandaloneV8Vm.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.v8.StandaloneV8Vm$2.consume(StandaloneV8Vm.kt:20)
    at org.jetbrains.v8.V8MessageDecoder.readContent(V8MessageDecoder.java:126)
    at org.jetbrains.v8.V8MessageDecoder.messageReceived(V8MessageDecoder.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.io.Decoder.channelRead(Decoder.java:38)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:155)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:950)
    at io.netty.channel.oio.AbstractOioByteChannel.doRead(AbstractOioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.oio.AbstractOioChannel$1.run(AbstractOioChannel.java:38)
    at io.netty.channel.ThreadPerChannelEventLoop.run(ThreadPerChannelEventLoop.java:52)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:742)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
2016-01-07 11:30:40,792 [ 104972]  ERROR - ins.io.ChannelExceptionHandler - WebStorm 11.0.3  Build #WS-143.1559.5 
2016-01-07 11:30:40,792 [ 104972]  ERROR - ins.io.ChannelExceptionHandler - JDK: 1.8.0_51 
2016-01-07 11:30:40,792 [ 104972]  ERROR - ins.io.ChannelExceptionHandler - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 
2016-01-07 11:30:40,793 [ 104973]  ERROR - ins.io.ChannelExceptionHandler - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2016-01-07 11:30:40,793 [ 104973]  ERROR - ins.io.ChannelExceptionHandler - OS: Windows 7 
2016-01-07 11:30:40,793 [ 104973]   INFO - ins.io.ChannelExceptionHandler - Channel will be closed due to error`

Comment: Seem to be created by you: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19724

Comment: Could be related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known bug, crash occurs on exception in eval(); see [WEB-19469](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19469)

Comment: Yes. Thanks Lena. I hope it gets fixed soon.